# iPhone app crashes with mach_msg_trap in UIWebView using specific URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, uiwebview

When I load a specific web page using UIWebView in my iPhone app, it crashes with a `mach_msg_trap` error. Other websites load fine in my app.
Try this URL as an example:

```
[rssArticle loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fan-f1.com/actualite-8387-F1-Massa-pourrait-quitter-lhopital-de-Budapest-dans-10-jours.html"]]];
```

This specific web page makes the app crashing, and loading that same URL in Safari mobile makes it crash the same way (the homepage of that website produces the same result).
Do you have the same behaviour on your iPhone? Should I report a bug or is it some known problem with websites sharing a common specificity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`mach_msg_trap` is a function which wraps the generic kernel message-sending in iPhone OS and Mac OS X, so covers a multitude of sins from sockets to inter-thread communication. Do you have more information about your crash which could help understand what's going on?

Comment: As far as I remember, a few days ago I managed to see a stack pointing at a lot of JSCore method calls, but now when I run the app, the call stack is showing only a few standard calls: main, UIApplicationMain, GSEvent, GSEventRun, GSEventRunModal, CFRunLoopRunInMode, CFRunLoopRunSpecific, mach_msg, and mach_msg_trap.
If I manage to get more details, I'll post them here.
Can you reproduce the bug?

Comment: That sounds like some other thread crashed, and your main thread is just waiting in the event loop.

Comment: Did anybody managed to track down this issue? i'm having the same issues wit uiwebview and js. I can't use WKWebView that's not an option for me